# How to responsive Django CKEditor

Tags: django, ckeditor

I'm already downloaded CKEditor for my blog web application.

But when I visit this site by mobile, it looks very bad, because it's not responsive. How can I convert this into [responsive design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)?

I am using Django 3.5.

```python
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {

    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'height':500,
        'width':450,
        'extraPlugins': 'codesnippet',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Bold', 'Italic','Image', 'Underline'],
            ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink'],
            ['RemoveFormat', 'Source','codesnippet']
        ]
    },
    'special':
      { 'toolbar': 'Special',
      'wdith':100,
      'toolbar_Special':
      [
      ['CodeSnippet','Youtube'],
      ['Styles', 'Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'SpellChecker', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
      ['Link', 'Unlink',],
      ['Image','Table', 'HorizontalRule'],
      ['TextColor', 'BGColor'],
      ['Smiley', 'SpecialChar'],
      ['Source'],
      ],'extraPlugins': 'codesnippet',
      }
}
```

Comment: try removing `height` and `width` from the toolbar maybe that'll solve the issue?

Comment: Sir i also do as u can see i am aslo add width:100 but it's not working though width aslo changed but it shows same in all platform

Comment: let me check then, it's usually pretty responsive for me, btw don't call people 'sir' here. No need to be so formal. and welcome to SO. BTW can you paste a screenshot of how your CKeditor is showing up?

Answer (score 0):

if u want to do responsive need to change setting in config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {

config.width = "auto";
config.height = "auto";
```

Answer (score 0):

I used 
'width': '100%',
'height': '50vh',

BTW, in your special setting, 'width' was mis-spelled.

Answer (score -1):

This is how i used and it worked:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'width': 'auto',       # <--------- LIKE THIS
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'],
            ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I am using bootstrap for styling and it works perfectly.